# ExecutorService.awaitTermination() returns true, even if tasks aren't finished

Tags: java, concurrency

Here is my parser class:

```
public class InputFilesParser {

private ExecutorService executorService;
private volatile Throwable thrownError;

public InputFilesParser(int poolSize) {

        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize, (r) -> {

            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((thread, e) -> {
                //this should be called before the thread has finished.
                this.notifyOnException(thread, e);
            });

            return t;

        });

    }

}

public void parseFile(Path inputFilePath) throws Throwable {

        //if exception is set, then no more files will be processed.
        if (this.thrownError != null) {

            //execution will stop here because an error will be thrown from waitToFinish()
            this.waitToFinish();

        }

        this.executorService.execute(() -> {

            //this will always throw an exception which have to be handled by the above mentioned uncaughtExceptionHandler.
            this.processFile(inputFilePath);

        });

}

private void processFile(Path inputFilePath) {

    throw new RuntimeExecption();

}

public void waitToFinish() throws Throwable {

        this.executorService.shutdown();

        while (true) {

            try {

                //if statement will be entered only when awaitTermination returns true, meaning all the tasks are finished.
                if (this.executorService.awaitTermination(STOP_CHECK_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {

                    synchronized (this) {

                        //in this scenario, after all tasks are finished, the thrownError should be set
                        if (this.thrownError != null) {

                            //I expect to get this output
                            System.out.println("Exception: " + this.thrownError);
                            throw this.thrownError;

                        }

                        //but I get this output
                        System.out.println("No exception: " + this.thrownError);

                    }

                    break;

                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                LOG.info("An interruption occurred", e);

            }

        }

}

private synchronized void notifyOnException(Thread thread, Throwable t) {

    //if the thrownError isn't set, then set it here so that waitToFinish() will know that an error occurred.
    if (this.thrownError == null) {

        this.thrownError = t;

    }

}
```

}

on the calling thread, I have the following:

```
InputFilesParser ifp = new InputFilesParser(poolSize);
try {
    for (Path f : files) {

        //each parsing will throw an exception in this scenario
        ifp.parseFile(f);

    }
    //an exception should be detected and the error thrown, but actually this is not happening, but printing No exception... message.
    ifp.waitToFinish();
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Although there is an exception thrown, the calling thread gets in waitToFinish() method, printing null for the thrown exception:

> Thread: Thread-5. No exception: null

This means that awaitTermination returns true, before the exception is set in `notifyOnException` method. But `notifyOnException` method is called from a thread run by this executor service. In my opinion there is a problem with my understanding, or there is a problem with `java`.

Any idea which one of this :) ? In my opinion, this shouldn't be possible. Am I missing something about setUncaughtExceptionHandler method and the way how it handles the exceptions? Although from documentation it seems that this method is called by the thread throwing the exception.

> public void setUncaughtExceptionHandler(Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler eh)

> Set the handler invoked when this thread abruptly terminates due to an uncaught exception.

> A thread can take full control of how it responds to uncaught exceptions by having its uncaught exception handler explicitly set. If no such handler is set then the thread's ThreadGroup object acts as its handler.

Parameters:
eh - the object to use as this thread's uncaught exception handler. If null then this thread has no explicit handler.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google can't find a `notifyOnException()` method.  Got a link to the documentation?

Comment: @markspace `notifyOnException()` is my method. You can see it down there in the OP.

Comment: I think you need to produce a [mcve], this code is way too complex for people to guess at what the problem might be.  Your comment in the code says `waitToFinish()` "will stop here" but waitToFinish is a rather large and complex method, could you break down exactly where the problem is?  What output do you see, and what do you expect to see instead?  Please don't rely on external resources for the [mcve], please use something like a StringReader to generate a self-contained input stream.

Comment: This could also conceivably be due to thread-safety issues, where a write to `thrownError` is not visible to another thread.

Comment: @LouisWasserman this is not the case, as I put all writes in a synchronized block, as you can see.

Comment: @markspace Please have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that my assumption in regard to `UncaughtExceptionHanlder`'s method call is wrong.
Java docs says [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html):

> public static interface Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler

> Interface for handlers invoked when a Thread abruptly terminates due to an uncaught exception.
> When a thread is about to terminate due to an uncaught exception the Java Virtual Machine will query the thread for its UncaughtExceptionHandler using Thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler() and will invoke the handler's uncaughtException method, passing the thread and the exception as arguments.

With other words, it is not the thread itself which calls the `UncaughtExceptionHandler`'s method, but JVM. This means that there is no constraint in regard to the order of operations when `awaitTermination` is called.